# Update one table columns according to another table colum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

[image]

I want to update TableA.id = TableB.id WHERE TableA.elements = TableB.elements

Comment: Is id a primary or unique key in table a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join

```
update tablea a
 join tableb b  on a.elements=b.elements
set a.id=b.id
```